# Switching a connection that a table uses

Tags: excel, database-connection, connection-string

I have a pivot table that uses a connection to our development database. I want to move the connection to the production database, because it gets updated more often. The databases have the same structure, just outdated data. Is there a way to just switch the connection over to the production database if my table originally gets the information from the development database?

I want to do this without losing the other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to data table in excel.  Select pivot table and then choose properties then go to the definition tab and make your change.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to only have the connection string? I have to send this excel sheet to other people and I don't want to have to send the connection file also.

Comment: The connection string property box persists so when you sent it to other people they will not need your connection file.  If you are doing a lot of updating of connections I would recommend having a network share or a sharepoint data connection library and centralize production connection files and checking always use connection file.  So you can update there instead of reseeding workbooks all of the time.